# Does this pun make sense to native speakers?

Tags: puns

> If one were to play the pipes without an audience, would that constitute an "exercise in ***flutility***"?

Not sure if that pun works on native speakers…

Comment: Why does it matter whether there is an audience or not? Maybe because it's **useless** in the opinion of the speaker?

Comment: If the pun is supposed to be a combination of "futility" and "fluidity," I can tell you that I got it, but it definitely took some thinking.

Comment: “The pipes” is probably not the right word.  You might try “the fife” and then the combination of ***futility*** and ***flute*** will make sense.

Comment: Amazing nit picking in the comments here.  Yes, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: I caught the pun alright

Comment: I got it instantly.  I like it.

Comment: Pronunication will matter. At first I read it as "flu-tility" which makes no sense. Re-reading as "flut-ility" does.

Comment: As puns go, it's a bit worse than most.  Of course, some people would consider that to be a good thing.

Comment: "Pipes" is the wrong word for a British audience - they would probably take it to mean "bagpipes" which is going down the wrong rabbit hole. In the UK, "fife" is not a common word and the instrument itself is almost obsolete - though it seems to be more common in the USA. Try something like "tin whistle" instead, for a UK audience.

Comment: American English speaker here--while I do get it I have a problem with "playing the pipes"--I wouldn't think of a flute as a pipe although it actually is one.  The first thing that comes to mind for "playing the pipes" is a pipe organ, second would be bagpipes.

Comment: Ugh.. yes that elicits a nontrivial groan.

Comment: You guys changed my mind, I'm glad to say. OK, no-one would fail to understand that pun. At the same time, it would hardly be worth the trouble of trying to understand it, without taking the "nit-picking" into account.